# VB Compiler can not recognize xlPasteValues

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have this simple VB.NET code to copy range from a worksheet and paste to another worksheet, **paste values only** :

```
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

Dim xlWorkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(in_Path)

'Define the Excel Source Sheet
Dim xlWorkSheetSource As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkSheet
xlWorkSheetSource = CType(xlWorkbook.Sheets(in_WorkSheetSource),Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkSheet)
'Activate the Source Worksheet
xlWorkSheetSource.Activate()

Dim xlRange1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
xlRange1 = xlWorkSheetSource.Range("A13:O20")
xlRange1.Copy()

'Define the Excel Destination Sheet
Dim xlWorkSheetDestination As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkSheet
xlWorkSheetDestination = CType(xlWorkbook.Sheets(in_WorkSheetDestination),Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkSheet)
'Activate the Source Worksheet
xlWorkSheetDestination.Activate()

xlWorkSheetDestination.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

xlWorkbook.Save
xlWorkbook.Close
```

But I have this **error** :

```
No compiled code to run
error BC30451: 'xlPasteValues' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. At line 21
```

Obviously, `xlPasteValues` is not a var to declare.

Is there any other way to get it done ?

I am using the namespace :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Comment: I am not sure whach Excel COM library or Interop namespace includes it, but you can find all of the xlPasteType's enumerated in the doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype.  `xlPasteValues` is -4163.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I have checked that link, when I use -4163 in my case instead of xlPasteValues I get this error :

Error ERROR Validation Error No compiled code to run
error BC30512: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to 'XlPasteType'. At line 21

Comment: Either take strict off, or convert it to xlPasteTypes.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thanks, that solved the issue

Comment: OK, I have posted it as an answer, so that you can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.Net (unlike VBA) you have to qualify enumerated values.  So change this line:

```
xlWorkSheetDestination.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

to this:

```
xlWorkSheetDestination.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteType.xlPasteValues)
```